# Overuse of 'I' in a memoir

Tags: style, pronouns

Is it acceptable to use I multiple times over and over  when writing dialogue and quotes for memoirs.  I have been told that if you are using quotes in dialogue that nothing is wrong.  I am reading a story now and see the word I as many as 25 times on the page.

Comment: So, you’ve come here hoping for an *aide-mémoire*, have you now? :)

Comment: If what you are saying about yourself is interesting no one will mind; and if it is not no one will care.

Comment: "I" understand how you feel. The overuse of it makes it sound too repetitive and where it doesn't fit properly or to the point where the reader is bored.

Answer (score 4):

Use of "I" is perfectly acceptable in a narrative first-person memoir.  Especially if it is written in either a conversational or confessional style (i.e., a diary).

Quotation marks for dialog or excerpts are appropriate, and should of course be written in as faithful a recording as possible.  (or, if it's a fictional "memoir", should be from the POV of the fictional source.)